# Does "a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$" mean the same as "the power set of $\Omega$"?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, terminology

I am reading a probability theory book, and the wording is confusing me.
To my understanding, the $\sigma$-algebra of a sample space $\Omega$ could be the minimal $\sigma$-algebra or the power set of $\Omega$.

So, does "a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$" mean a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a collection of subsets of $\Omega$? Or does it refer to the power set of $\Omega$?

Comment: It refers to some particular subsets of the sample space that form a sigma algebra. The understanding is that we have agreed on some particular sigma algebra to use. Then, any further results are with respect to that. So it is common to say “fix a sigma algebra.” The power set is one particular one, it is usually the one we use when the sample space is finite or countably infinite.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) on $\sigma$-algebras. It gives a good example of a finite $\sigma$-algebra that is not the power set.

Comment: Apparently, “a σ-algebra of ALL subsets of Ω
” is the same as “the power set of Ω".

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $\Omega$, the term "a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$" is just a way of saying a $\sigma$-algebra whose maximal element is $\Omega$. That is, when describing a collection $X$ as a $\sigma$-algebra, you must specify the $\Omega$ such that each element of $X$ is a subset of $\Omega$, and $\Omega \in X$.

I would say that referring to $X$ as a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ is probably the standard terminology, whereas the phrase "$\sigma$-algebra with maximal element $\Omega$" is my own terminology (I actually prefer $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$, but I don't know if anyone uses either).

Anyway, the power set of $\Omega$ is just one particular $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$. Another example (from the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra)) is $\Omega = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and $X = \{ \emptyset, \{ a, b \}, \{ c, d\}, \{ a,b,c,d \} \}$.

Comment: Thank you!  "a σ-algebra of subsets of Ω" is just a way of saying a σ-algebra whose maximal element is Ω. And  “a σ-algebra of ALL subsets of Ω ” is the same as “the power set of Ω".

Comment: @newbornalive I'm surprised it comes up as "A $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $\Omega$" and not "THE $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $\Omega$", considering it is unique for a given $\Omega$.